# Error relocating /usr/bin/mono: getrandom: symbol not found

Tags: mono, alpine-linux

I'm trying to install mono inside an alpine 3.8 container and I received this message when running mono:

```
Error relocating /usr/bin/mono: getrandom: symbol not found
```

Is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: in case Alpine is officially supported by Mono, it seems you found a bug; otherwise this might be a symptom that Mono is not supported in this platform; how about you fix the problem and contribute a PullRequest? Mono is opensource

Answer (score 0):

[mono](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/testing/x86/mono) is only available in [edge testing](http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/x86_64/) alpine repository. In order to install it, we need to have [musl](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.9/main/x86_64/musl) at least version [1.1.20](https://github.com/frol/docker-alpine-mono/issues/9), which is available in alpine [v3.9 main](http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main/x86_64/) or [edge main](http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main/x86_64/) repositories.

So, you have two options to proceed:

**1.** Install `musl` from `alpine v3.9` repository on `alpine v3.8` base image and install `mono` from `alpine edge testing` after that:

```
FROM alpine:3.8
RUN apk add --no-cache --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main musl\>1.1.20
RUN apk add --no-cache --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing mono
CMD mono
```

**2.** Install `mono` from `alpine edge testing` on `alpine v3.9` base image:

```
FROM alpine:3.9
RUN apk add --no-cache --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing mono
CMD mono
```